# Alternatives to dotfuscator suite?

Tags: .net, obfuscation, application-security

I've been looking for solutions that provide a couple of types of protection and dotfuscator has been what I've landed on each time I look. Specifically, I like:

- code obfuscation
- their usage analytics
- tamper detection/notification
- shelf-life enforcement

Now, I know that there's lots of alternatives to the first, some of which are free, but are there alternatives to the others? It's not that I don't want to pay the cost of dotfuscator suite, but I want to be informed before I write the cheque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you can try the [CryptoLicensing](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) + [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) package which will get you all that you want:

- Usage analytics - CryptoLicensing provides ability to notify the license service whenever the license is validated (typically app start-up). You can mine these notification entries to determine usage stats.
- Tamper detection/notification - Both Crypto Obfuscator and CryptoLicensing has tamper detection features.
- Shelf-life enforcement - I am assuming this means nothing more than time limited licenses? If so, CryptoLicensing allows this using various parameters - max usage days, max unique usage days, max executions, absolute date of expiration, max run-time, max cumulative run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Use '[Phoenix Protector](http://ntcore.com/)' obfuscator found here on ntcore.com created by Daniel Pistelli. It does work reasonably well and its free...

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good alternative with [bitHeltmet](http://www.bithelmet.com). It provides code obfuscation with very interesting features.